# Executed Stored Procedure using Dapper

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I am trying to execute a stored procedure using Dapper but I get two types of errors:

1. Error parsing column 9 (fTaxInvoiceNumber=INV0000000028PPN - String)
2. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is the code to execute the stored procedure:

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionFactory.ConnectionString("RebateSystem"));
db.Open();

try
{
    var result = db.Query<PracticeRebateOrders>("GetPracticeRebateOrderByInvoiceNumber", new
    {
       TaxInvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber
    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
    db.Close();
    db.Dispose();

    return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw;
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPracticeRebateOrderByInvoiceNumber] 
    @TaxInvoiceNumber NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP(1) 
      [fPracticeRebateOrdersID]
      ,[fPracticeID]
      ,[fPracticeUserID]
      ,[fCreatedDate]
      ,[fInvoiceInCredits]
      ,[fPurchaseDate]
      ,[fPracticeRebateOrderStatusID]
      ,[fRebatePaymentRunID]
      ,[fRebateBatchID]
      ,[fTaxInvoiceNumber]
   FROM 
      [PracticeRebateSystem].[dbo].[PracticeRebateOrders]
   WHERE 
      fTaxInvoiceNumber = @TaxInvoiceNumber
END
```

Comment: Can you show what `PracticeRebateOrders` looks like? or at least what `fTaxInvoiceNumber` looks like? Also - on the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - when does that happen, exactly? is it possible that this is simply because there were no rows, and thus `result` was `null`? As a side note, your `try`/`catch` is not useful, and you should really be using `using` here, not `try` - i.e. `using(var db = new SqlConnection(...)) {...}`. Note that you don't need to `Close()` / `Dispose()` if you use `using`, so you can just `return db.Query<...>(...).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: fTaxInvoiceNumber looks like this - INV0120000028PPN. The error is taking place where I execute the stored proc. var result = db.Query<PracticeRebateOrders>("GetPracticeRebateOrderByInvoiceNumber", new
                {
                    TaxInvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber
                }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault(); . Ok I will take note of that thanks

Comment: No, you misunderstand me; I am asking what the **property** `fTaxInvoiceNumber` looks like, on your `PracticeRebateOrders` class. Not what the value is; but *what is the member declaration*.

Comment: O sorry for that, here is what it looks like: public string fTaxInvoiceNumber ;
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
  public string TaxInvoiceNumber
  {
   get { return fTaxInvoiceNumber; }
   set { fTaxInvoiceNumber = value; }
  }

Comment: hmmm; that's odd - that should work fine; any .StackTrace info I can use here?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but based on the code available in the question and in the comments I have this... which works fine and successfully...

```
public void SO24605346_ProcsAndStrings()
{
    connection.Execute(@"create proc #GetPracticeRebateOrderByInvoiceNumber @TaxInvoiceNumber nvarchar(20) as
        select @TaxInvoiceNumber as [fTaxInvoiceNumber]");
    string InvoiceNumber = "INV0000000028PPN";
    var result = connection.Query<PracticeRebateOrders>("#GetPracticeRebateOrderByInvoiceNumber", new
    {
        TaxInvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber
    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();

    result.TaxInvoiceNumber.IsEqualTo("INV0000000028PPN");
}
class PracticeRebateOrders
{
    public string fTaxInvoiceNumber;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string TaxInvoiceNumber { get { return fTaxInvoiceNumber; } set { fTaxInvoiceNumber = value; } }
}
```

I'm happy to help, but I cannot reproduce an issue. Looks fine here.